# Redimensionar um MDI Form sem bordas

Tags: c#, redimensionamento, mdi

Já encontrei muitas dicas de como redimensionar um Form sem bordas, todas funcionais e boas, porém não funcionam quando se trata de um MDI Form.

Alguém tem uma dica funcional de como redimensionar um MDI Form?

Desde já meus agradecimentos.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com `MDI Form ` **`sem bordas`**?

Comment: o sem bordas é para o usuário não redimensionar... Se voce esta falando para redimensionar via código ai já é outra coisa.

Comment: Vamos lá amigo, deixa eu te explicar!   Como coloquei "Já encontrei muitas dicas de como redimensionar um Form sem bordas, todas funcionais e boas", sim, sem bordas, mas quanto ao que o usuário faz, é o que permito, então ele poderá redimensionar o form. Tudo funciona bem, porém para trabalhar com form abertos em um TabControl, necessariamente o main form precisa ser MDI, e aí é que está o problema, todos os controles ~de redimencionamento que implementei são desativados. O que preciso saber é como redimencionar um Form MDI, sem bordas, pelas quatro laterais e pelos 4 cantos!

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se resolvi seu problema pois esta muito confuso sua pergunta...

No construtor do child form, adicione essas linhas de código:

```
this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

No evento Form_Load, Você deve adicionar essa linha de código:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: Grato pelo retorno DaniloLoko! Bom vamos ver se eu explico melhor! Tenho um MainForm sem bordas que eu montei segundo minhas necessidades.Em fim, remodelei segundo a interface que eu precisava, inclusive podendo redimenciona-lo. Porém quando abro um form de cadastro, a exemplo, eu abro em um TabPageControl, para isto o MainForm tem que ser um MDI form e passando para MDI form, perde  a possibilidade de redimencionar o MainForm. E quero implementar isto e preciso de ajuda!